# Let $G$ be a group and $A,B\leq G$ abelian subgroups such that $AB=G$. Show $A\cap B\leq Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am working on an exercise that states:

> Let $G$ be a group and $A,B\leq G$ abelian subgroups such that $AB=G$. Show $A\cap B\leq Z(G)$.

My attempt so far:

$Z(G)=\{z \in G \mid \forall g \in G, zg = gz\}$

Because $A,B\leq G$ are abelian subgroups $A\cap B\leq G$ is an abelian subgroup.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: It is easy to show that every element in $A\cap B$ commutes with all elements $AB$. Since $AB=G$, every element in $A\cap B$ commutes with all elements in $G$. Therefore, $A\cap B\subseteq Z(G)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x \in A \cap B$ and let $g=ab \in G$ arbitrary, with $a \in A, b \in B$. Then $xab=$ (using $A$ is abelian, and $x \in A$) $axb=$ (using $B$ is abelian and $x \in B$) $=abx$. Hence $x \in Z(G)$.

**Note** (added June $23^{rd} 2022$) A famous theorem of [N. Itô](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0062?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B404%5D,%22panX%22:0.689,%22panY%22:0.744,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.447%7D), dating from $1955$, states that if a group $G=AB$ with $A$ and $B$ both abelian subgroups, then $G'$ must be abelian ($G$ is called *metabelian*). This is not hard to prove, read the paper in the link (warning: in German, but the formulas are easy to follow).

Answer (score 1):

I will use the one-step subgroup test.

Since $A,B\le G$, they are themselves groups and their identity is the identity in $G$. Thus $e\in A\cap B$. Hence $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are abelian, all elements $x$ of $A\cap B$ commute with all elements of $ A$ and of $B$. But $G=AB$, so that all $g\in G$ can be written as $g=ab$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, so

$$\begin{align}
xg&=x(ab)\\
&=(xa)b\\
&=(ax)b\\
&=a(xb)\\
&=a(bx)\\
&=(ab)x\\
&=gx,
\end{align}$$

meaning $x\in Z(G)$. Hence $A\cap B\subseteq Z(G)$.

Let $h,k\in A\cap B$. Since $A\cap B\le G$ (as $A,B\le G$), we have, in particular, that $hk^{-1}\in A\cap B$.

Hence $A\cap B\le Z(G)$.

Comment: Would someone please explain the downvote?